# Trying to make pass protected page guest available

Tags: php

i have page which users can upload an advert if they regster, I want it to be so guests can upload too, when i comment out my part where it says if not logged in redirect It breaks as the query has no user id, can anybody explain how make guest user?

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/setSession.php");
session_start();


//to include all core files
$_SESSION['temptab']=5;
include "include.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
  $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
}else{
    $_SESSION['temptab']=5;
    header('location:login.php');
}

$tab=5;
$subtab='viewads';
if(isset($_GET['adsID'])){
    $adsID = $_GET['adsID'];
}else if(isset($_POST['adsID'])){
    $adsID = $_POST['adsID'];
}else{
    $adsID = 0; 
}
if (isset($_POST['updte'])){
  $updte = $_POST['updte'];
}else{
  $updte = 0;   
}
if($adsID>0){
    $sql_ads="Select * from ADS a,ADCONTENTS ac where a.adCONTENTID=ac.adCONTENTID and a.adsID=".$adsID;
    $res_ads=getXbyY($sql_ads,"array");
    $rows_ads=count($res_ads);

    $factory = new TypeFactory($dbName);
        $o1= $factory->get_object($adsID,"ADS"); 
        $o->adCONTENTID=$o1->adCONTENTID;
    $factory1 = new TypeFactory($dbName);
        $o= $factory1->get_object($o->adCONTENTID,"ADCONTENTS"); 
}
$sql_p="select * from PAYMENTPLAN where isACTIVE=1";
$res_p=getXbyY($sql_p,"array");
$rows_p=count($res_p); 

$sql_category="select * from ADCATEGORIES ";
$res_category=getXbyY($sql_category,"array");
$rows_category=count($res_category);


$sql_user="Select * from USERS where userID=".$userID;


$res_user=getXbyY($sql_user,"array");
$rows_user=count($res_user);
include "Thumbnail.class.php";
if($updte>0){
    if($_FILES['adIMAGE1']['name'] != ""){
        $btext = $_FILES['adIMAGE1']['tmp_name'];
        $filename_1 = $_FILES["adIMAGE1"]["name"];
        $file_basename1 = substr($filename_1, 0, strripos($filename_1, '.')); // strip extention
        $file_ext1 = substr($filename_1, strripos($filename_1, '.')); // strip name
        if (($file_ext1 == ".JPG" || $file_ext1 == ".jpg" || $file_ext1 == ".gif" || $file_ext1 == ".jpeg")) {
            // rename file
            $newfilename1 = $file_basename1."_admin_1".$file_ext1;
            if (file_exists("myads/".$newfilename1)) {
                unlink("myads/".$newfilename1);
            }
                $o->adimageSRC1 = $newfilename1;
                $destfile = 'myads/'.$o->adimageSRC1;
                $destfile11 = 'myads/thumbs/'.$o->adimageSRC1;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["adIMAGE1"]["tmp_name"],$destfile);
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($destfile);
                if($width > $height){
                    $limit = ceil($width/150);
                }else{
                    $limit= ceil($height/150);
                }
                $newwidth = ceil($width/$limit);
                $newheight = ceil($height/$limit);
                $imagename1=$destfile;
                //for ad thumbs
                $thumb=new Thumbnail("$imagename1");
                $thumb->size_auto($newwidth,$newheight); // [OPTIONAL] set the biggest width or height for thumbnail
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Hmargin=10; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text horizonatal margin in pixels
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Vmargin=10;
                $thumb->txt_watermark=""; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text [RECOMENDED ONLY WITH GD 2 ]
                $thumb->txt_watermark_color='ffffff'; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text color , RGB Hexadecimal[RECOMENDED ONLY WITH GD 2 ]
                $thumb->txt_watermark_font=2; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text font: 1,2,3,4,5
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Valing='BOTTOM'; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text vertical position, TOP | CENTER | BOTTOM
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Haling='RIGHT';
                $thumb->process();
                $filename=$destfile11;
                $status=$thumb->save($filename);    

        }elseif(empty($file_basename1)) {
        } else {
            // file selection error
            $msg = "Only jpg or gif files can be uploaded.";
            //unlink($_FILES["adIMAGE1"]["tmp_name"]);
        }
    }else if($_POST['imgsrc1']!=''){
        $o->adimageSRC1=$_POST['imgsrc1'];
    }else{
        $o->adimageSRC1 ='';
    }   
    if($_FILES['adIMAGE2']['name'] != ""){
        $btext2 = $_FILES['adIMAGE2']['tmp_name'];
        $filename_2 = $_FILES["adIMAGE2"]["name"];
        $file_basename2 = substr($filename_2, 0, strripos($filename_2, '.')); // strip extention
        $file_ext2 = substr($filename_2, strripos($filename_2, '.')); // strip name
        if (($file_ext1 == ".JPG" ||  $file_ext2 == ".jpg" || $file_ext2 == ".gif" || $file_ext2 == ".jpeg")) {
            // rename file
            $newfilename2 = $file_basename2."_admin_2".$file_ext2;
            if (file_exists("myads/".$newfilename2)) {
                // file already exists error
                unlink("myads/".$newfilename2);
            } 
                $o->adimageSRC2 =  $newfilename2;
                $destfile2 = 'myads/'.$o->adimageSRC2;
                $destfile22 = 'myads/thumbs/'.$o->adimageSRC2;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["adIMAGE2"]["tmp_name"],$destfile2);
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($destfile2);
                if($width > $height){
                    $limit = ceil($width/150);
                }else{
                    $limit= ceil($height/150);
                }
                $newwidth = ceil($width/$limit);
                $newheight = ceil($height/$limit);
                $imagename2=$destfile2;
                //for ad thumbs
                $thumb=new Thumbnail("$imagename2");
                $thumb->size_auto($newwidth,$newheight); // [OPTIONAL] set the biggest width or height for thumbnail
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Hmargin=10; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text horizonatal margin in pixels
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Vmargin=10;
                $thumb->txt_watermark=""; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text [RECOMENDED ONLY WITH GD 2 ]
                $thumb->txt_watermark_color='ffffff'; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text color , RGB Hexadecimal[RECOMENDED ONLY WITH GD 2 ]
                $thumb->txt_watermark_font=2; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text font: 1,2,3,4,5
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Valing='BOTTOM'; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text vertical position, TOP | CENTER | BOTTOM
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Haling='RIGHT';
                $thumb->process();
                $filename=$destfile22;
                $status=$thumb->save($filename);    

        }elseif(empty($file_basename)) {
        } else {
            // file selection error
            $msg = "Only jpg or gif files can be uploaded.";
            //unlink($_FILES["adIMAGE1"]["tmp_name"]);
        }

    }else if($_POST['imgsrc2']!=''){
        $o->adimageSRC2=$_POST['imgsrc2'];
    }else{
        $o->adimageSRC2 ='';
    }   
    if($_FILES['adIMAGE3']['name'] != ""){
        $btext3 = $_FILES['adIMAGE3']['tmp_name'];
        $filename_3 = $_FILES["adIMAGE3"]["name"];
        $file_basename3 = substr($filename_3, 0, strripos($filename_3, '.')); // strip extention
        $file_ext3 = substr($filename_3, strripos($filename_3, '.')); // strip name
        if (($file_ext1 == ".JPG" ||  $file_ext3 == ".jpg" || $file_ext3 == ".gif" || $file_ext3 == ".jpeg")) {
            // rename file
            $newfilename3 = $file_basename3."_admin_3".$file_ext3;
            if (file_exists("myads/".$newfilename3)) {
                // file already exists error
                unlink("myads/".$newfilename3);
            }
                $o->adimageSRC3 = $newfilename3;
                $destfile3 = 'myads/'.$o->adimageSRC3;
                $destfile33 = 'myads/thumbs/'.$o->adimageSRC3;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["adIMAGE3"]["tmp_name"],$destfile3);
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($destfile3);
                if($width > $height){
                    $limit = ceil($width/150);
                }else{
                    $limit= ceil($height/150);
                }
                $newwidth = ceil($width/$limit);
                $newheight = ceil($height/$limit);
                $imagename3=$destfile3;
                //for ad thumbs
                $thumb=new Thumbnail("$imagename3");
                $thumb->size_auto($newwidth,$newheight); // [OPTIONAL] set the biggest width or height for thumbnail
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Hmargin=10; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text horizonatal margin in pixels
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Vmargin=10;
                $thumb->txt_watermark=""; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text [RECOMENDED ONLY WITH GD 2 ]
                $thumb->txt_watermark_color='ffffff'; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text color , RGB Hexadecimal[RECOMENDED ONLY WITH GD 2 ]
                $thumb->txt_watermark_font=2; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text font: 1,2,3,4,5
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Valing='BOTTOM'; // [OPTIONAL] set watermark text vertical position, TOP | CENTER | BOTTOM
                $thumb->txt_watermark_Haling='RIGHT';
                $thumb->process();
                $filename=$destfile33;
                $status=$thumb->save($filename);    

        }elseif(empty($file_basename)) {
        } else {
            // file selection error
            $msg = "Only jpg or gif files can be uploaded.";
            //unlink($_FILES["adIMAGE1"]["tmp_name"]);
        }

    }else if($_POST['imgsrc3']!=''){
        $o->adimageSRC3=$_POST['imgsrc3'];
    }else{
        $o->adimageSRC3 ='';
    }   
    if($_POST['youtubevideo']!=''){
        $o->advideoTYPE=1;
    }else{
        $o->advideoTYPE=0;
    }
    if($_POST['youtubevideo']!=''){
        $o->advideoSRC=$_POST['youtubevideo'];
    }else{
        $o->advideoSRC='';
    }
    $o1->adTITLE=$_POST['adTITLE'];
    $o1->price=$_POST['price'];
    if($_POST['showPRICE']=='on'){
        $o1->showPRICE=1;
    }else{
        $o1->showPRICE=0;
    }
    $o1->adDESC=$_POST['addesc'];
    if($adsID==0){
        $o->adCONTENTID=0;
        $o->advideoIMAGE='';
        $o->isACTIVE=1;
        $o1->advertiserID=$userID;

        $o1->adtypeID=$_POST['adCATEGORY'];
        $o1->adCATEGORYID=$_POST['cat'];
        $o1->adPROVIDER='';
        $o1->adLINK=$_POST['adLINK'];
        $o1->planID=$_POST['planID'];
        $o1->slideSHOW=0;
        for($e=0;$e<$rows_p;$e++){
            if($res_p[$e]['planID']==$o1->planID){
                $o1->expireDATE=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0, date("m")+$res_p[$e]['noofMONTHS'], date("d"), date("y")));
                $o1->slideSHOW=$res_p[$e]['slideSHOW'];
                break;
            }
        } 
        $o1->impMADE=0;
        $o1->clicks=0;
        $o1->postedDATE=todaysdate();
        $o1->startDATE=todaysdate();
        $o1->isACTIVE=1;
        $o1->paymentdetailID=0;
        $foo = $o1->price;
        /*if($o1->planID==5 && $userID<=30 && $o1->adtypeID==1){
            if($res_user[0]['freeAd']==0){
                $o1->paymentdetailID=-1;
                $sql_updteusers="Update USERS set freeAd=1 where userID=".$_SESSION['userID'];
                    setXbyY($sql_updteusers);
            }
        }else{*/
            $sql_plan="select * from PAYMENTPLAN where planID=".$o1->planID;
            $res_plan=getXbyY($sql_plan,"array");

            if($res_plan[0]['price'] == "0.00" && $res_plan[0]['isACTIVE']==1){
                $o1->paymentdetailID=-2;
            }
        //}
        $factory2 = new TypeInsertor($dbname);
            $o->adCONTENTID = $factory2->insert_object($o,"ADCONTENTS");
            $o1->adCONTENTID=$o->adCONTENTID;
        $factory3 = new TypeInsertor($dbname);
            $o1->adsID = $factory3->insert_object($o1,"ADS");
            $adsID=$o1->adsID;
        if($o1->paymentdetailID==0){
            header('location:makepayment.php?adsID='.$o1->adsID);
        }else{
            header('location:viewads.php?msg=1');
        }
    }else if($adsID>0){
        $o1->adsID=$res_ads[0]['adsID'];
        $o->adCONTENTID=$res_ads[0]['adCONTENTID'];
        $factory2 = new TypeUpdater($dbname);
            $o= $factory2->update_object($o,"ADCONTENTS");
        $factory3 = new TypeUpdater($dbname);
            $o1=$factory3->update_object($o1,"ADS");

        /* $sql_updte="Update ADS set adDESC='".addslashes($_POST['addesc'])."' where adsID=".$o1->adsID." ";
            setXbyY($sql_updte); */
        if($o1->paymentdetailID==0){
            header('location:makepayment.php?adsID='.$o1->adsID);
        }else{
            header('location:viewads.php?msg=2');
        }
        //header('location:makepayment.php?adsID='.$o1->adsID);
    }
}
if($adsID>0){
    $sql_ads="Select * from ADS a,ADCONTENTS ac where a.adCONTENTID=ac.adCONTENTID and a.adsID=".$adsID;
    $res_ads=getXbyY($sql_ads,"array");
    $rows_ads=count($res_ads);
}
include "includes/header.html";
include "html/placeanad.html";
include "includes/footer.html";
?>
```

Comment: you expect us to wade through this? please make your question specific, and only include relevent code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set $userID = 0. Assuming your Users table is auto-incrementing IDs starting at 1, the query will just return no results and your advertiserID for guests would all be set to 0. So maybe replace that if block with something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){
  $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
}else{
  $userID = 0;
}
```

Comment: Then i get query was empty :(

Comment: You can create a new user account for the guests and change $userID = 0 to $userID = <ID of your new guest user>.